# Different kinds of fruit or fruits

Tags: word-form

> different kinds of fruit
>
> different kinds of fruit**s**

Which one is correct? Or both are correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the botanical sence, "fruit" is often [treated as uncountable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fruit#Usage_notes), so "different kinds of fruit" is certainly correct. It is sometimes treated as plural, so "kinds of fruits" is not grammatically incorrect, but is less common. The first form is preferred.

Comment: I think the second one would sound better and be more correct as just "Different fruits", without "kinds of"

Comment: @Jorge Urreta: "different kinds of fruit" is perfectly idiomatic, as James K says; also, "different fruits" doesn't have quite the same meaning as "different kinds of fruit".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo What does each expression mean, then?

Comment: @userr2684291:  It depends on the context. But the basic difference is that **kind** is an explicit reference to the species or variety; without it, the difference could be of a different nature. For example, you could say *We've been getting peaches from these two trees for years now. The one on the left gets sun all day, but the one on the right is shaded in the afternoon by that tall maple. They're the same species of peach tree, but they produce very different fruits.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I thought it was quite the opposite. Would you mind having a look at [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/25303/71740) at ELU? At [pearsonlongman.com](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00231.html) it says: "You use **fruits** to refer to different species of fruit."

Comment: @userr2684291: I gave an example where **fruits** was used to refer to the  fruit produced by two trees of the same species. That does not preclude the use of the word **fruits** to refer to species, nor does it preclude the use of the singular **fruit** in that same context (it could have said "very different fruit").  The rule is not as hard-and-fast as you imagine it to be.  **fruits** often means "more than one species of fruit" but it can refer to an actual plural of the same species.  The word **different** makes a difference.

Comment: Compare: *...showy white **fruits** which remain on the tree well into December* (*The genus Sorbus: mountain ash and other rowans* here: https://books.google.com/books?id=6xdFAAAAYAAJ&q=%22very+different+fruits%22&dq=%22very+different+fruits%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG5rSvoZ_UAhXBx4MKHfHOBMMQ6AEILDAB)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo 1, They're the same species of peach tree, but they produce very different fruits/fruit.  2, showy white fruits/fruit which remain on the tree well into December    What are the nuances?

Comment: The difference is an abstract one, the difference between the collective singular and the plural.  The collective singular **fruit** could be used to refer to the tree's *yield*. "That tree gets  sun all day and its fruit is plentiful."  The plural **fruits** could be used to refer to the growths individually: "That peach tree was planted where a black walnut once stood; its fruits are small and not very sweet."